# Hash table update value in c

Tags: c, hash, key, glib

I am using Glib for hash table. I need to update value from key. Is there a way without delete and insert to hash table for update.

I found `g_hash_table_replace ()`

```
gboolean
g_hash_table_replace (GHashTable *hash_table,
                      gpointer key,
                      gpointer value);
```

Is this update value from key, if it's how can i use this function.

Solve:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <glib.h>

GHashTable * hash_operation = NULL;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
char *from;
int gg = 3;
char *a=strdup("32"),*b=strdup("24"),*c=("mübarek");

hash_operation = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
g_hash_table_insert(hash_operation, a, gg);

from = strdup(g_hash_table_lookup(hash_operation, a));
printf("%s\n",from);
g_hash_table_replace (hash_operation, a,c);
from = strdup(g_hash_table_lookup(hash_operation, a));
printf("%s\n",from);
free(a);
free(b);
free(c);
free(from);

return 0;
}
```

Problem solved.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Like, why can't you use that function (please show the code you tried)? Or is that function unsuitable, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of the function `g_hash_table_replace` is quite easy:

It takes 3 arguments:

- `hash_table`: It is of course you hashtable, so in your case `hash_operation`
- `key`: The key you want to edit. (I belive your key is `a`)
- `value`: The value that should be stored in the GHashTable at `key`

A quick example would be:

```
GHashTable *table = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
gchar *key = "key1";
g_hash_table_insert(table, key, "Hello");
g_hash_table_replace(table, key, "World");
gchar *result = (gchar*) g_hash_table_lookup(table, key);
g_print("Result: %s\n", result); //Prints: "Result: World"
```